# test angular2 on virtualbox?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, port, localhost

I have ubuntu and I am developing Angular2 webapp,  I want to test my webapp on IE11, so I installed Windows10 on my VirtualBox, but how to reach localhost:4200 from the Windows10 which is in the VirtualBox, Any help? Thank you.

Comment: You cannot reach `localhost` from other systems, including VMs. You need to make it listen on a wider scope.

Comment: I was able to reach localhost through writing 10.0.2.2 and I could read localhost from the VM but the problem that I could not read localhost:4200! the thing I tried 10.0.2.2:4200 but could not success

Comment: Yes. It is *exactly* like I said. You *cannot* reach something listening on 127.0.0.1 or ::1 from outside the operating system. Make `angular2-cli` or whatever listen on 10.0.2.2 then.

Answer (score 0):

The dev server prevents connections from outside as a security precaution. If you wish to run the dev server without it being blocked run

ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check